# TableViewCell delete is not animated on alertViewController action

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I am adding a "delete" button inside a `tableview cell`, which presents an `alertController` in alert mode. On the "destroyAction" I delete the data and fire delete the row from table.

```
let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action) in
let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell!)

   self.numbers.remove(at: (indexPath?.row)!)
   tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .right)
    }
}
```

Problem is that the row is deleted without animation.

But when I wrap it inside with `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` then the animation will work.

```
let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action) in
let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell!)

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.numbers.remove(at: (indexPath?.row)!)
   tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .right)
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why this made animation to work and if there is a simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in edit actions?

Comment: Having a delete button is part of the UI experience. Also i am trying to understand how the alertcontroller affect the animation, and how dispatching the action on main queue is solving the animation problem.